# Why is pytest asking to specify --tx

Tags: python, pytest, travis-ci, pytest-xdist

After multiple successful tests, pytest is suddenly throwing this error:

```sh
$ pytest -vvv -x --internal --oclint -n -32
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/pre-commit-hooks/code/pre-commit-hooks, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: xdist-1.31.0, forked-1.1.3
ERROR: MISSING test execution (tx) nodes: please specify --tx
```

This is my pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
markers =
    oclint: marks tests as slow (deselect with '-m "not slow"')
    internal: marks tests as checking internal components. Use this if you are developing hooks
```

`-n #` is from pytest-xdist, which is an addon to pytest.
This was strange to me because pytest on a travis linux build was working just fine until the last iteration.

### Question

Why is pytest asking me to add `--tx` for my tests?

Comment: I am adding this question/answer because I solved it for myself and wanted to share. No further answers are necessary (but if there's more context to the underlying reason that it's parsed this way, by all means - knowledge is power).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fat-finger a dash after the -n number like `-n -32`, pytest will complain about a missing `--tx` option. In other words the number after -n cannot be negative and what you want to use instead is `-n 32`.

`--tx` is normally used like so to invoke a Python2.7 subprocess:

```py
pytest -d --tx popen//python=python2.7
```

More information about using `--tx` as part of pytest can be found in the pytest-xdist [docs on this flag](pytest -d --tx popen//python=python2.7).

Comment: How does `-n` interact with `--tx`? Are they completely independent options? Wouldn't `-n 8` be the equivalent of `--tx 8*popen`?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.1/xdist.html), `-n 8` will run pytest over 8 CPUs whereas `--tx 8*popen` will open 8 subprocesses, which could all be on one CPU.

Comment: Running pytest over 8 cpus due to Python GIL would mean that pytest has to launch 8 subprocesses. And also opening 8 subprocesses which could be 1 CPU. Sure but that's why you have pre-emptive CPU schedulers which will schedule the 8 subprocesses over cores.

Comment: My answer concerns fat fingering a dash. You are polluting my answer with irrelevant discussion. Please ask your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same `pytest-xdist` error but for a different reason. I had set `--forked --dist=loadfile` but did not specify `--numprocesses`. Setting that option fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: Similar error can happen if one specifies e.g. `dist=loadfile` without specifying `-n 32`.